# SUBSTRING error while converting VARCHAR to DATE

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using the following code to convert date from a varchar to an acceptable date format.

```
create view v1 as 
Select name,time,
CAST(CAST(SUBSTRING( [ENTDATE],1,2)+
SUBSTRING( [ENTDATE],3,2)+ --month
SUBSTRING( [ENTDATE],5,2)  --day
AS VARCHAR(10)) 
AS DATE) as ENTDATE)
from table1
```

Currently the dates appear as 990415.

There are over 100000 records. Around 10 records for the date are not clean and have length less than 6. eg: 7912.

These records are leading to conversion failed error. Is there any way I can handle these 10 records while converting?

Comment: Use a case expression in your select list, treat too short values separately!

Comment: You could screen for them using a CASE statement: `CASE WHEN LEN([ENTDATE]) < 6 THEN '1/1/2000' ELSE CAST(...) END`. There are many ways to solve the problem, so it would be helpful to know if this is a one time conversion or if this is supposed to be used in an ongoing process.

Comment: It is a one time conversion!!

Comment: There are lots of ways of "handling" them.   What do you want to do with them?

Comment: If this is a one-time conversion then may be it's better to update or filter out inconsistent values?

Answer (score 0):

When you're sure that the records have either 8 or 6 positions, you can use `nullif` in your query.

```
create view v1 as 
Select name,time,
CAST(CAST(SUBSTRING( [ENTDATE],1,2)+
SUBSTRING( [ENTDATE],3,2)+ --month
nullif(SUBSTRING( [ENTDATE],5,2), '')  --day
AS VARCHAR(10)) 
AS DATE) as ENTDATE)
from table1
```

This will return NULL when the record has 6 positions.